# TCP strange RST packet terminating connection

Tags: linux, tcp, protocols, firewall

The question is we have the following setup and we have noticed sometime client sends `RST` packet to terminate initial TCP handshake connection and application gets a timeout.

> [10.5.8.30]------[Linux FW]-------[10.5.16.20]

Wireshark:

You can see in Wireshark RST packet, I thought its FW sending RST but in capture packet coming from `10.5.8.30` so what could be wrong here? why connection getting reset randomly, if I try next time then it will work.

[image]

Comment: The fact that the source IP for the RST is 10.5.8.30 doesn't mean that 10.5.8.30 really sent it. There are firewalls and various other intermediary devices that forge such packets. Try capturing on both ends.

Comment: You are goddamn right!! someone was sharing same IP address so it was ip duplication

Comment: Glad to hear. I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: The RST packet *has* to have that source address to be identified as resetting that connection, regardless of who sent it.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the source IP for the RST packet is `10.5.8.30` doesn't mean that it really came from `10.5.8.30`.

There are firewalls and various other intermediary devices that [forge such packet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_reset_attack)s. Try capturing on both ends to check whether `10.5.8.30` did, in fact, send the RST. It doesn't make sense for a client to send a TCP Syn and then a RST.

Comment: small addition how did i find duplication IP, in packet capture i saw some packets coming from different `mac` address with same IP and it gave me some clue to dig more.